Serilog SQL Server Sink not filling custom column, and no error in selflog
See issue on Serilog repo: https://github.com/serilog-mssql/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/issues/534
I have set up database logging which works, but my custom column is always null even though the property exists and I have added a mapping for the column. SelfLog to console and debug is enabled, but no error shows up. I can trigger a visible selflog by setting an invalid connection string, so I think selflogging is working correctly.
I expect Serilog to fill the column with the value of the property when the property matches the mapping. I also expect Serilog to emit an error on selflog when an error prevents writing to the column.
Serilog packages used in the project:

Serilog: 3.1.1 (also occurred on 3.0.1)
Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer: 6.6.0
Serilog.Extensions.Hosting 7.0.0
Serilog.Extensions.Logging 7.0.0
Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File 3.0.0
Serilog.Sinks.Console 5.0.1
Serilog.Sinks.File 5.0.0

Target framework and operating system:
.NET 7.0, Windows 10
Reproduction of the Serilog configuration code:
https://gist.github.com/LouisMach/a6c41f017dcb2fcf3d7e2ea79d880c82#file-program-cs
Reproduction of the application code:
Code: https://gist.github.com/LouisMach/a6c41f017dcb2fcf3d7e2ea79d880c82#file-service-cs
SQL script: https://gist.github.com/LouisMach/a6c41f017dcb2fcf3d7e2ea79d880c82#file-tbllog-sql
The property is correctly added to the properties and scope part of the log entry, this is the content of the property column:
<properties>
    <property key='SourceContext'>MyProject.Services.x.Service</property>
    <property key='AssetNumber'>123</property>
    <property key='ActionId'>643b5dd4-1147-4c4b-aacf-e3f6766cbeac</property>
    <property key='ActionName'>MyProject.Controllers.x.Controller.Sync (projname)</property>
    <property key='RequestId'>redacted</property>
    <property key='RequestPath'>/api/v1/project/sync</property>
    <property key='ConnectionId'>redacted</property>
    <property key='Scope'>
        <sequence>
            <item>Asset Number: 123</item>
        </sequence>
    </property>
</properties>

If I set the wrong connection string, I get the following error in Console and Debug Output:
2024-04-30T08:11:32.8056928Z Unable to write batch of 1 log events to the database due to following error: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
So it seems that errors from Serilog are being written, so I would expect error output when Serilog is unable to write to the column.
I have tried adding .Enrich.FromLogContext() to the logger configuration, but it didn't help which makes sense because I am using scopes instead of the log context.
I have specified the column to map the property, including the length of the column. I have also tried to leave out the mapping but the problem persists.
This occurs when logging messages with and without an exception.

Have you tried passing _logger.BeginScope() a Dictionary<string, object>?  Something like: _logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> {{"AssetNumber", x.Assetnumber}}.  See this thread: https://nblumhardt.com/2016/11/ilogger-beginscope/

@BrettJaner I have and it results in the same problem, but thank you for the suggestion.

I had the same problem recently, updating Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer from version 5.7.1 to 6.6.1. My column was defined as a nvarchar(36), but I tried to enter a guid. Calling .toString() on the guid fixed the problem.
Logging it to the properties did still work without calling .toString(), so the problem seems to lie in the mapping to the custom column.
